# How to open a keyboard in Android with EditText?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, buttonclick

I have-

- EditText &
- Button

How can I open a soft keyboard when one selects the edittext view, the user can write anything and it should display in the edittext.

I used the below code but the keyboard doesn't come up-

```
 EditText edit= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.list);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(edit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Any idea how I can open the keyboard and close it again by using back button?

Comment: The input method editor should automatically open when the user taps on the `EditText`, assuming the device does not have a physical keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is my function to open the keyboard :

```
protected void showKeyBoard(final View v){
    v.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            v.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` in manifest File.

and

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" is done.
But how do I use edittext.requestFocus();